# Вопрос о статических файлах в Django

Tags: css, django, wamp

Ребят, мне нужно реализовать с помощью Django несколько функций. Для реализации каждой функции я буду использовать отдельный Django-проект и приложение. Чтобы django корректно обрабатывал статические файлы, мне нужно все css скинуть в каждый Django-проект в папку static? Если я использую wamp, все равно это необходимо делать?

Comment: Отдельные Django-приложения ещё было бы понятно, а отдельные Django-проекты зачем?

Comment: Понял, не подумал) Так касаемо статических файлов, мне нужно все css-файлы переместить в static для каждого django-приложения?

Comment: Если вы будете использовать Django-приложения в пределах одного проекта, то Django автоматически прочитает все static'и из всех подключенных приложений. Если под фразой «для каждого django-приложения» вы имеете в виду дублирование файлов, то нет, дублировать их не надо

Comment: Не вижу смысла делать несколько проектов, а так djnago соберет в одну кучу все static файлы